# Make bootable USB/DVD from Mac for PC installation

Tags: usb, dvd, macbook

i've downloaded the last 64 bit version of ubuntu on my macbook pro. Now i want to create a bootable usb/dvd for install ubuntu on my pc, but i'm on a mac. My pc is formatted, so i can't use it. Please help!

Comment: You could use [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) for Mac to create a bootable Live-USB.

Answer (score 0):

Mac has a drive utility to burn ISO images. So you can write that ISO Ubuntu to your DVD on your mac which you can then us to boot on your PC. There are plenty of guids on how to write ISO images to a DVD on a Mac so follow on of those guides.

Not adding links as it will be out of date in a few months. So just google it.

https://www.google.com.au/search?q=iso+image+burn+osx&client=ubuntu&channel=cs&oq=iso+image+burn+osx

Comment: yes, the utility disco make a perfect bootable dvd for pc too.. thanks